# RESTeasy, JSON and null fields

Tags: java, json, jaxb, annotations, resteasy

When RESTeasy marshals a POJO into XML, it will skip null values by default.

However, when marshaling to JSON, null properties are included. Is there any way to force the JSON output to match the XML output?

Also i tried @XmlElement(required=false, nillable=true)) and it's not worked. I've been used only RESTeasy with Annotations.

Comment: Are you using a jackson or jettison provider? If you aren't using jackson try that.

Comment: is there solution without Jackson ? i would like to using only JAXB(native for JBOSS AS 7) for best performance, avoiding others "jar".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Jackson 2. Setup the following provider:

```
package com.recruitinghop.swagger;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JacksonJsonProvider() {
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          mapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
          mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
          mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT);
          mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
          mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
          super.setMapper(mapper);
    }

}
```

The Scala module is optional.

Comment: is there solution without Jackson ? i would like to using only JAXB(native for JBOSS AS 7) for best performance, avoiding others "jar".